# Bootstrap Modal and Jquery: [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique ids, however all IDs are unique

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Okay so I use bootstrap 4, and I have two different modal types in a single page. I use Ajax to fill up the body of these modals. Both of these forms that each modal opens are different from each other but they have certain ID tags that are similar.

This is how I fire up my modals.

```
$('#modalForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    ajaxLoad(button.data('href'), 'modal_content');
});

$('#modalFormLG').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    ajaxLoad(button.data('href'), 'modal_content_lg');
});
```

The problem is when I open one modal, and then when I open the second one, I get the following error in the browser console.

```
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #cashpaid: (More info: goo...)
```

However, I don't have any duplicates of IDs, it's just so that cashpaid ID is being used in both of those forms that each of these modals calls up into its body.

If I refresh the page and open the modal again, then I don't see this problem.

I have tried the following but it didn't have any effect on it

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(event) {
  $(this).removeData("bs.modal");
});
```

When I run the following two, then my modals becomes unresponsive for future use because they essentially delete that particular html data.

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(event) {
  $(this).empty();
});

AND

$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(event) {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

After opening and submitting the first modal, in the browser console when I type, "cashpaid" for example, I see the following.

```
<input type="number" id="cashpaid" name="cashpaid" min="0">
```

However, when I open the second modal and submit that form and when I type "cashpaid" in the browser console, I see the following.

```
HTMLCollection(2) [input#cashpaid.valid, input#cashpaid, cashpaid: input#cashpaid.valid]
```

So is there any method for bootstrap 4 modals to purge the remote url form's data when it closes down?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. What you posted so far is not enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Done. I have added more detail.

Comment: Modals are present in DOM even when they're not rendered. Consider creating a minimal runnable example which reproduces the error. Without one, how could anyone test a potential fix?

Comment: Thank you. I have rewritten my question more clearly based on what I know now. Basically, I need for bootstrap 4 modals to purge the remote URL form's data in its body, when it closes down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modalForm', function (event) {
  $('.modal-body', this).empty();
});
```

...will remove all child elements of `#modalForm .modal-body` after the closing modal animation ends.

**Note 1:** you only need to bind this once, not every time you open the modal.

**Note 2:** If you want this functionality on every modal (not only `#modalForm`), replace `#modalForm` with `.modal`. But keep in mind you can only do this with modals that get their contents generated upon reopening. A static modal will remain empty when reopened.

Comment: Wow this fixed it for me.. I added $('#modalForm').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $('.modal-body', this).empty();
    }); on both modals.. Thank you so much for helping me out.